# Why isn't the pdftk-php class hooking up with the pdftk.exe path?

Tags: php, pdftk

I'm currently trying to get the example that I downloaded with pdftk-php from GitHub to work by using the instructions from the following web page:

http://www.andrewheiss.com/blog/2009/07/29/installing-pdftk-php/

The database connection seems fine, but the pdf that gets produced only has a size of one kilobyte and Adobe Reader can't open it.
I'm assuming the problem must be in the pdftk-php.php file. 
For the passthru function near line 71 I originally used the following absolute path to the pdftk:

> passthru("C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe $pdf_original
>   fill_form $fdf_fn output - flatten");

This is exactly what I got from the command prompt when I typed "where pdftk". Since this didn't work I tried the following relative path:

> passthru("..\pdftk.exe $pdf_original fill_form $fdf_fn output -
>   flatten");

I was able to produce the form-fields.txt file just fine from the command prompt so I know pdftk is working, but I get an Undefined index error on line 47 of index.php when I submit the first and last name and the form that it produces can't be opened by Adobe Reader.

Answer (score 1):

Try single quotes around the command and double quotes around the path:

```
passthru('"C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe" $pdf_original fill_form $fdf_fn output - flatten');
```

I was able to get that format working yesterday.

I'm running into an issue where if I open the PDF in Chrome, it's populated, but if I open it with Acrobat, it's empty. Hopefully you have better luck!